# How do I solve this specific algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, concatenation

Given this array: arr = [ '00011100', '00000001', '00101101', '11111111' ];

If the element is on even position in the array, I have to remove all the chars with even index from this element and vice versa. Example:

The first element is on even position:
arr[0] = '0**0**0**1**1**1**0**0**'

The second element is on odd position:
arr[1] = '**0**0**0**0**0**0**0**1';

I have to remove those characters and return them as concatenated string.

Output of the whole array // 0110 0000 0011 1111

Please, help me solve this task :) Thank you in advance!

```
let enigma = "";
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
    let index = arr[i];
    let evenStr = ""; 
    let oddStr = "";
      if(index % 2 === 0) {
         for(let j = 1; j < index.length; j+=2) {
             evenStr += index[j];
         } enigma += evenStr;      
            } else if(index % 2 !== 0) {
         for(let x = 1; x < index.length; x+=2) {
             oddStr += index[x];
         } enigma += oddStr;
    }
}
console.log(enigma) //0110000100111111;
```

This is my code so far but the output I recieve is slightly different :/

Comment: what problems do you encounter with what you have tried?

Comment: `arr[0] = '00011100'`. Are you using `zero-based` array index to calculate which is in even position and which in on odd.

Comment: How are you calculating the `even` or `odd` in `'00011100'`

Comment: Yes. The first element from the array is on even posotion. --> arr[0];

Comment: And the next element is on odd position --> arr[1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential solution to your problem.

**Using reduce()**

```js
const removeOddIndex = ( str ) => {
 return str.split("").filter( ( element, index ) => index % 2).join("");
}

const removeEvenIndex = ( str ) => {
 return str.split("").filter( ( element, index ) => !( index % 2 )).join("");
}

const array = [ '00011100', '00000001', '00101101', '11111111' ];

const result = array.reduce( ( acc, cur, index ) => {
  if( index % 2 ) {
    acc[index] = removeEvenIndex( cur );
  } else {
    acc[index] = removeOddIndex( cur );
  }
  return acc;
}, array).join("")

console.log(result)
```

**Using map()**

```js
const removeOddIndex = ( str ) => {
 return str.split("").filter( ( element, index ) => index % 2).join("");
}

const removeEvenIndex = ( str ) => {
 return str.split("").filter( ( element, index ) => !( index % 2 )).join("");
}

const array = [ '00011100', '00000001', '00101101', '11111111' ];

const result = array.map( ( element, index ) => {
  return index % 2 ? removeEvenIndex( element ) : removeOddIndex( element )
} ).join("");

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The answer returns multidimensional array. Do you have any idea how I can get the final output as concatenated string "0110000000111111". Im not familiar with ```reduce()``` yet.

Comment: I edited my solution to give you the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const arr = ["00011100", "00000001", "00101101", "11111111"];

const getEven = (value) =>
  value
    .split("")
    .filter((el, i) => i % 2 === 0)
    .join("");
const getOdd = (value) =>
  value
    .split("")
    .filter((el, i) => i % 2 === 1)
    .join("");

const result = arr
  .map((val, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) return getOdd(val);
    else return getEven(val);
  })
  .join("");

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter by taking the remainder of the item of the outer element and the elment's values.

```js
const
    array = ['00011100', '00000001', '00101101', '11111111'],
    result = array.map(([...a], i) => a.filter((v, j) => i % 2 !== j % 2).join(''));

console.log(result);
```